# GPIO.cleanup() doesn't clear my screen

Tags: gpio, screen

I use a 16*2 screen (refe: EA W162-X3LW) for a project. I manage to display some text and scrolling text on it as I wanted but when I kill the code with the Keyboard, my GPIOs are not cleared as they should be. If I run the code a first time after booting the RPi the screen display the text properly. If I kill it then I get some Warnings telling me my channels are already in used and the screen display weird characters... I have to shutdown the RPi to clear the screen and clean my GPIOs. Does anybody knows what I making wrong ?

Here is the code :

```
# The wiring for the LCD is as follows:
# 1 : GND
# 2 : 5V
# 3 : Contrast (0-5V)*
# 4 : RS (Register Select)
# 5 : R/W (Read Write)       - GROUND THIS PIN
# 6 : Enable or Strobe
# 7 : Data Bit 0             - NOT USED - CAN BE USED FOR 8 BITS
# 8 : Data Bit 1             - NOT USED - CAN BE USED FOR 8 BITS
# 9 : Data Bit 2             - NOT USED - CAN BE USED FOR 8 BITS
# 10: Data Bit 3             - NOT USED - CAN BE USED FOR 8 BITS
# 11: Data Bit 4
# 12: Data Bit 5
# 13: Data Bit 6
# 14: Data Bit 7
# 15: LCD Backlight +5V**
# 16: LCD Backlight GND

#import
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# Define GPIO to LCD mapping
LCD_RS = 23  # Blue cable 
LCD_E  = 18  # Green cable
LCD_D4 = 12  # Yellow cable
LCD_D5 = 16  # Yellow cable
LCD_D6 = 20  # Yellow cable
LCD_D7 = 21  # Yellow cable

# Define some device constants
LCD_WIDTH = 16    # Maximum characters per line
LCD_CHR = True
LCD_CMD = False

LCD_LINE_1 = 0x80 # LCD RAM address for the 1st line
LCD_LINE_2 = 0xC0 # LCD RAM address for the 2nd line

# Timing constants
E_PULSE = 0.00005
E_DELAY = 0.00005

def main():
  # Main program block
  GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)       # Use BCM GPIO numbers
  GPIO.setup(LCD_E, GPIO.OUT)  # E
  GPIO.setup(LCD_RS, GPIO.OUT) # RS
  GPIO.setup(LCD_D4, GPIO.OUT) # DB4
  GPIO.setup(LCD_D5, GPIO.OUT) # DB5
  GPIO.setup(LCD_D6, GPIO.OUT) # DB6
  GPIO.setup(LCD_D7, GPIO.OUT) # DB7

  # Initialise display
  lcd_init()

  while True:
    str_pad = " " * 16

    # HELLO
    lcd_stringfix("HELLO",LCD_LINE_1)
    time.sleep(2)
    lcd_stringfix("ALL RIGHT",LCD_LINE_1)

    my_long_string = "P1 : " "P2 : " "P3 : "
    my_long_string = str_pad + my_long_string
    for i in range (0, len(my_long_string)):
     lcd_byte(LCD_LINE_2, LCD_CMD)
     lcd_text = my_long_string[i:(i+15)]
     lcd_stringscroll(lcd_text,1)
     time.sleep(0.4)
    lcd_byte(LCD_LINE_2, LCD_CMD)
    lcd_stringscroll(str_pad,1)

    time.sleep(3) # 3 second delay

def lcd_init():
  # Initialise display
  lcd_byte(0x33,LCD_CMD)
  lcd_byte(0x32,LCD_CMD)
  lcd_byte(0x28,LCD_CMD)
  lcd_byte(0x0C,LCD_CMD)
  lcd_byte(0x06,LCD_CMD)
  lcd_byte(0x01,LCD_CMD)
  time.sleep(E_DELAY)

def lcd_stringfix(message,line):
  # Send string to display

  message = message.ljust(LCD_WIDTH," ")

  lcd_byte(line, LCD_CMD)

  for i in range(LCD_WIDTH):
    lcd_byte(ord(message[i]),LCD_CHR)

def lcd_stringscroll(message,style):
  # Send string to display
  # style=1 Left justified
  # style=2 Centred
  # style=3 Right justified

  if style==1:
    message = message.ljust(LCD_WIDTH," ")
  elif style==2:
    message = message.center(LCD_WIDTH," ")
  elif style==3:
    message = message.rjust(LCD_WIDTH," ")

  for i in range(LCD_WIDTH):
    lcd_byte(ord(message[i]),LCD_CHR)

def lcd_byte(bits, mode):
  # Send byte to data pins
  # bits = data
  # mode = True  for character
  #        False for command

  GPIO.output(LCD_RS, mode) # RS

  # High bits
  GPIO.output(LCD_D4, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D5, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D6, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D7, False)
  if bits&0x10==0x10:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D4, True)
  if bits&0x20==0x20:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D5, True)
  if bits&0x40==0x40:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D6, True)
  if bits&0x80==0x80:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D7, True)

  # Toggle 'Enable' pin
  lcd_toggle_enable()

  # Low bits
  GPIO.output(LCD_D4, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D5, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D6, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D7, False)
  if bits&0x01==0x01:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D4, True)
  if bits&0x02==0x02:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D5, True)
  if bits&0x04==0x04:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D6, True)
  if bits&0x08==0x08:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D7, True)

  # Toggle 'Enable' pin
  lcd_toggle_enable()

def lcd_toggle_enable():
  # Toggle enable
  time.sleep(E_DELAY)
  GPIO.output(LCD_E, True)
  time.sleep(E_PULSE)
  GPIO.output(LCD_E, False)
  time.sleep(E_DELAY)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()

  try:
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    main()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
  finally:
    lcd_byte(0x01, LCD_CMD)
    lcd_string("Goodbye!",LCD_LINE_1)
    print "Interrupt"
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume the error is the superfluous early call to main() as you gave no explanation for why it was there.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()

  try:
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    main()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
  finally:
    lcd_byte(0x01, LCD_CMD)
    lcd_string("Goodbye!",LCD_LINE_1)
    print "Interrupt"
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Perhaps you should have

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    main()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
  finally:
    lcd_byte(0x01, LCD_CMD)
    lcd_string("Goodbye!",LCD_LINE_1)
    print "Interrupt"
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Thanks joan. You are right this was a mistake. Also lcd_string to be changed in lcd_stringfix. However when I run the code the weird characters are still displayed on my screen... The screen is not cleared.

Comment: Did the code ever work?  Have you ruled out a wiring problem?

Comment: The GPIO.cleanup() has never work properly. I always have the warnings. I didn't experience any wiring issue... The only way that works to clear the screen is to unplug the Raspi, even reboot doesn't work. When I try to display an empty character, weird character are displayed instead.

Comment: Does writing text work?  Is it only commands, like clear screen,  which are failing?

Comment: Yes writing text work. Scrolling text also. Just GPIO.cleanup() does not do anything apparently.

Comment: Is it actually called?  Do you see "Interrupt" on the screen?

Comment: I change the end of the code like this :

  finally:
    lcd_byte(0x01, LCD_CMD)
    lcd_stringfix("Goodbye!",LCD_LINE_1)
    time.sleep(3)
    print "Interrupt"
    time.sleep(3)
    lcd_stringfix("",LCD_LINE_1)
    GPIO.cleanup()

Now the screen is cleared but my lines inverted... I think it is a bug I am going to disconnect everything and try again.

Comment: I reboot the Pi now it works, I really do not understand why before I got weird character... I didn't touch the wiring... Now, when I run the code a first after rebooting everything work. If I kill the code with the keyboard the screen is cleared. But when I run it another time my lines are inverted... I do not understand why.

Answer (score 1):

I have an I<sup>2</sup>C backpack equipped 16x02 LCD and I see strong similarities with the above code in what I had with mine.  I too got odd termination effects so I changed the `finally:` block to be:

```
  finally:
    lcd_string("    Goodbye!    ",LCD_LINE_1)
    lcd_string("                ",LCD_LINE_2)
    time.sleep(E_DELAY)
    lcd_byte(0x01, LCD_CMD)
    time.sleep(E_DELAY)
    lcd_byte(0x01, LCD_CMD)
    time.sleep(E_DELAY)
```

Now I do not use the GPIO pins in quite the same way so I did not have a `GPIO.cleanup()` call - you will probably want to put it in.  I do write to both lines on the display and I send the command to clear the display `lcd_byte(0x01, LCD_CMD)` AFTER that and a delay - I see you clear the display and then write a "Goodbye" message.  If you refer to the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitachi_HD44780_LCD_controller) on this type of display you will note that there is a significantly longer delay for the clear display (and the cursor home) commands compared to all the others to execute.  I actually do it twice but in hindsight that may be overkill - however I do another delay after the second one before the program ends.

I would suggest that you include a delay after the GPIO.cleanup() too.